# Howgrave-Graham lattice attack on NTRU

Tags: cryptanalysis, lattice-crypto, attack, ntru, lenstra-lenstra-lovasz

I am lookin for a good example to illustrate this attack on NTRU using low parameters but I failed to do that, The attack consist to use LLL reduction on A basis of NTRU Lattice, let us use the column convention, how Can I use the first vector to retrieve (f,g)???

Comment: Isn't h, the public-key in NTRU? I think you're asking about (f,g) which belongs to R^2.

Comment: yeah thanks  Mr @AaqibBashir

Comment: The column has $2N$ entries, so it is really a vector $(f', g') \in R^2$ (the first $N$ entries correspond to the $N$ coefficients of $f'$...). If your reduction is successful, then this column is short and the polynomial $f'$ that you get is the secret $f$ or a small multiple of $f$, which is usually already enough to decrypt the ciphertexts.